# Слово "глаза"

Tags: этимология

Подумалось. Раньше глаз назывался око. Было еще просторечное "зенки" (от слова "зеница"). А откуда взялось слово "глаз" и как вышло, что оно вытеснило слово "око"?

Comment: Если от европейских, то, возможно, от немецкого glas - стекло.

Comment: ...от европейских? Такая тяга к краткости изложения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Происходит от др.-русск. глазкы стекляныи «стеклянные шарики» (Ипатьевск. летоп. под 6622 г.). Связано, очевидно, с польск. głaz «камень, скала», głaźny «гладкий, ловкий», niegłaźny «неловкий, ухабистый», макед. Глазна река, букв. «Каменка». Вероятнее первонач. знач. «шар» или «камень». Знач. «глаз, око» ср. с русск. диал. ша́ры мн., также «глаза», польск. gały «глаза» и др. Возм., слав. glazъ «шарик» связано с церк.-слав. глезнъ, глезно «лодыжка», др.-исл. klakkr «ком», шв. klakk (из *glog^no-). Затруднительно в морфологическом отношении возведение к* glad-zъ, ср. gladъkъ русск. гла́дкий. Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера; см. Список литературы.
Трубачев: русск. глаз в современном знач. отмечено лишь с конца XVI — начала XVII в., первонач. — об одном глазе, глазном яблоке.