# Откуда взялось слово "глаз"?

Tags: этимология

Раньше было слово "око", причем, как я понимаю, это слово общее для многих языков (например, испанское "ojo"). Но откуда вдруг тогда взялось слово "глаз"? И насколько позже "ока" он появился?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Вы уже задавали этот вопрос. [Здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5719/%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0)

Comment: Забыл, наверное.)))

Comment: В любом случае надо начинать с поиска.